# Missing Ubuntu 12.04 security update for Apache 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.12?

Tags: 12.04, updates, apache2

On July 31st 2017, Ubuntu released Ubuntu Security Notice 3373-1 ( https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3373-1/) related to Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I thought it was nice of them to release a security update for 12.04, which is no longer officially supported. The new package version should be Apache2 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.12.

However, when doing an `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, no new version of Apache is available on 12.04. The USN refers to [this launchpad package page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/2.2.22-1ubuntu1.12), but it doesn't exist. According to the [apache2 source package in Precise](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/apache2) on launchpad, the latest version is 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.11, not .12.

Does anybody know where that package has gone?

Comment: The information in this USN is somehow misleading. But I doubt that askubuntu is the right place for this question.

Comment: Why is the information in the USN misleading? And why do you believe this is not the right place to ask this question?

Comment: It's quite ridiculous that this question is marked as off-topic because "This question is specific to an end of life Ubuntu release. " It's almost as if the question hasn't even been read. You can do better than this, AskUbuntu.

Comment: Like I said, this is just not the right place to ask for that kind of support. Better to place your question in a specialized [mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/)